# Django Storages failing to upload static files in nginx and docker configuration

Tags: django, docker, nginx, amazon-s3, uwsgi

I am unable to get NGINX (which I think is the culprit) to work with django-storages when a media file is uploaded. It will receive static files from my S3 bucket, but it just refuses to post to it. Whenever an image is uploaded to the site I will get a NGINX 500 Internal Server Error. It works with the default django runserver application and I am unsure what is causing this to fail. This is all run in a docker container. Here is what I have:

Settings, showing how storages is set-up

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'sitename-staticfiles'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= 'access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 'secret_key'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'sitename')]

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

custom_storages.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

nginx.conf

```
user nobody;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        server {
              listen 80 default_server;
              listen [::]:80 default_server;
              server_name sitename.com localhost;
               location / {
                        include         uwsgi_params;
                        uwsgi_param     SCRIPT_NAME /;
                        uwsgi_pass          unix:///var/tmp/sitename.sock;
                        proxy_redirect     off;
                        proxy_buffering    off;
                        proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host  $server_name;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                }
        }

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings

# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = %d

# Django's wsgi file
module          = sitename.wsgi

# the virtualenv (full path)
# home            = /

#socket=:8000
# http = 0.0.0.0:8000
# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 4
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /var/tmp/sloopsnoop.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint-prod.sh
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static/
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media/
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=sitename_db_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```